# Check if a number is already presented on an array with values introduced by the user

Tags: c, for-loop, unique, variable-length-array

I am learning to program on C and I am trying to create a program that scan certain amount of numbers established by the user, and store them on an array that I will use later, but the numbers introduced by the user can't be repeated, so I am trying to implement this restriction with a comparation inside a for loop.
I've tried with other kind of loops bu I cant make it work appropiately.

Thanks!

Here is my code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int n;
    int i;
    int num;
    printf("Introduce the amount of numbers you will register \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int N[n];
    printf("Introduce your numbers \n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    scanf ("%d",&num);
    {
        if (num == N[i])
        {
            printf("You already introduced this number, try again");
        }   

            N[i]=num;
            printf("____________ \n");  
    }
    getchar ();
    getchar ();
    return 0;   
}
```

When I run this program the output is this one, and I have no idea why

```
Introduce the amount of numbers you will register
5
Introduce the first value
1
____________
____________
____________
____________
You already introduced this number, try again ____________

--------------------------------
```

Comment: The user decides, how long the array is going to be

Comment: Let us try again: Consider `int n; ... int N[n];` --> How big is array `N[]` at that time **before** `scanf("%d",&n);` occurs?

Comment: `int N[n];`: at that exact moment `n` is not yet initialized it contains an undetermined  value.

Comment: Besides the problem of when `n` gets entered, you're going to need two loops, not one.  You're going to need an outer loop, with `i` running from 0 to `n-1`, asking the user to input a number.  And then you're going to need a second, "inner" loop, where for each number the user enters, you check to make sure it isn't among the numbers already entered.

Comment: The first 3 comments still stand.... How big is your array `int N[n];` with `n` is 0?

Comment: Thanks, I've already changed the  `n` problem, I will try to implement the inner loop, your retroalimentation helped a lot.

Comment: @Carmen _"I've already changed the ` n` problem"_: no, you haven't, at least not in the code in your question.

Comment: So what I need to do is to, declare the array after scanning `n` ?

Comment: @Carmen yes, obviously. Instructions are executed sequentially.

Comment: Now that the `n` problem has been solved: Are you aware that you only ask the user for one single number?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should've started the loop after scanning the variable. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you may not declare a variable length array with zero elements

```
int n=0;
//...
int N[n];
```

You need to declare the array after entering a positive value in the variable n.

```
int n;

//...

printf("Introduce the amount of numbers you will register");
scanf("%d",&n);

int N[n];
```

Also as the array was not initialized then this comparison

```
if (num == N[i])
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Also you have to enter values within the loop,

You need to write something like the following

```
for ( i=0; i<n;)
{
    scanf ("%d",&num);

    int j = 0;

    while ( j != i && num != N[i] ) ++j;

    if ( j != i )
    {
        printf("You already introduced this number, try again");
    }
    else
    {   
        N[i++] = num;
        printf("____________ \n");  
    }
}
```